# How get changes in DataTable in HTML-JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using `Datatable` for my table. I am facing few issue about updated data once `DataTable` is created.

I have 8 records. Pagination is of 5. Means there are 2 page. I have column of checkbox. When I convert table in `table.DataTable()`, I check data and it's fine using `DataTable.rows()`.

But when I perform any change, like uncheck any checkbox, change value of textbox, it doesn't reflect. 
After change I check value of `DataTable` using `console.log`. It show same data when it is initialized.

```
Steps to reproduce
1- Create table and convert into DataTable
2- Console.log table data
3- uncheck few checkbox and add some text in textbox
4- Console.log. It will show same data of Step-2.
```

Code:

```
HTML
<table id="products" style="width: 100%; font-family: Segoe UI,Tahoma,Arial;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <caption class="caption-title">Title</caption>
    <tbody id="ptbody"></tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select Product</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th style="display:none"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

JS
var ProductList = [];
ProductList.push("A");
ProductList.push("B");
ProductList.push("C");
ProductList.push("D");
ProductList.push("E");
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    strTableStructure = strTableStructure + "<tr>";
    strTableStructure = strTableStructure + "<td><input id='chk_" + ProductList[j] + "' checked='checked' type='checkbox'></td>";
    strTableStructure = strTableStructure + "<td>" + ProductList[j] + "</td>";
    strTableStructure = strTableStructure + "<td><input id='txtQty_" + j + "' type='text' maxlength='110' ></td>'";
    strTableStructure = strTableStructure + "</tr>";
}

$("#ptbody").html(strTableStructure);
var table = $('#products').DataTable();
```

Can anybody suggest me how to reflect changes when user check/uncheck or change value of textbox?

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar with the MyTasks button [here.](http://code.buzzword-cloud.com/post/2017/05/23/jquery-datatables-advanced-filtering)  Remember though that if the element you are attaching an event to is created by the datatables API then you need to reference the event differently.

```
$(document).on('event', 'element', function(){
   //do stuff
}
```

If you are trying to refresh the data use `table.ajax.reload();` or searching based on that event use `table.search('value').draw()`

Comment: I have submit button. I want to get latest value of checkboxes and textboxes in submit click. `console.log(objDataTable.rows())` should list updated value. It keeps same value of intial stage. Can you give me small example?

Comment: @NanjiMange before i edit my answer, can you post some of your markup?  I think i get it, but correct me here.  When you get those values using the objectDataTable.rows() it wont/is not giving the updated values.

Comment: I have added in question. Please suggest